# Get traffic for website to show attractive pictures

Tags: halal-haram, adultery

I have a website and bought traffic (visitors) from someone for my website. In this way, I made money from ads. Means people click on ads and I make money.

But I came to know that that person gives me traffic from Facebook source to use attractive and sometimes adult pictures and share the link with it. He posts 18+ pictures and gives link of my website.

People open the link to watch adult content but it opens my site.
Kindly tell me my money is considered halal or haram?

Answer (score 1):

It's haram because you more or less incite others to do haram things for you. Making other people to do haram things is haram by itself.